# improper matrix print out latex

Tags: matrix, printing, latex

using Latex to print out a Matrix , I noticed I can not place the numbers under each other correctly

here is the code, I really appreciate your help

```
\begin{center}

$ABD=
\begin{bmatrix}

      12610207.7\quad  5695754.3\quad  0\quad   0\quad  0\quad  0 \\
       5695754.3\quad  10737818.8\quad  0\quad  0\quad  0\quad  0 \\ 
       0\quad  0\quad  2800468.2\quad  0\quad  0\quad  0\\
       0\quad  0\quad  0\quad  37.3\quad  125.08\quad  0.12\\
       0\quad  0\quad  0\quad  125.08\quad  0.24\quad  0\\
       0\quad  0\quad  0\quad  0\quad  0\quad   0.12
\end{bmatrix}
\end{center}

$

\begin{equation}   \label{10} 
\end{equation}

\end{center}
```

Comment: Why have I received negative vote on this question ????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix (and other `tabular` or `array`) constructions use `&` to denote the column delineation, not `\quad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}
\begin{document}

Using \verb|bmatrix|:
\[
  ABD =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      12610207.7 &   5695754.3 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
       5695754.3 &  10737818.8 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\ 
             0   &         0   &  2800468.2 &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &   37.3  &  125.08 &  0.12 \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  125.08 &    0.24 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0.12
    \end{bmatrix}
\]

Using \verb|array|:
\[
  ABD =
    \left[\begin{array}{@{}
      S[table-format=9.1]
      S[table-format=9.1]
      S[table-format=7.1]
      S[table-format=3.2]
      S[table-format=3.2]
      S[table-format=1.2]@{}}
      12610207.7 &   5695754.3 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
       5695754.3 &  10737818.8 &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0    \\ 
             0   &         0   &  2800468.2 &    0    &    0    &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &   37.3  &  125.08 &  0.12 \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &  125.08 &    0.24 &  0    \\
             0   &         0   &        0   &    0    &    0    &  0.12
    \end{array}\right]
\]
```

With `bmatrix` you don't have to specify the number of columns. However, there is a limit, but [this can be extended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3519/5764).

[`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) was added to align the columns inside the `array` in a specific `table-format` way. Using a column specification `@{}*{6}{c}@{}` would have worked to produce a similar output as `bmatrix`.

Comment: Thank you so much , I haven't yet enough reputations to upvote your answer